# Performance Optimization for 2D game developed using Unity 3D game engine

Tags: unity

I have a game with almost 160 sprites in my resources folder.  I need 15 randomly selected sprites on each level (there are 7 levels).

I load those sprites which are required e.g. my random generator scripts generate 15 random numbers (completely unique from previously generated 15 numbers) and based on those number I load the sprites (sprites are numbered from 1-158 so I can easily load them).

My levels take some significant time to load, I think that pre-loading the sprites at the start of each level is taking time.   There are actually two folders, one for the questions and another for the answers.  Each question has 5 possible answers so I actually load 15 * 5 sprites on each level and save them in an array.

Should I load all the sprites once the game is loaded? Or Should I pre-load all the Sprites in advance?

Thanks in advance I am really looking forward for answers.

NOTE: There are almost thousands of tiles(100px by 100px in size) on each level, I know this also has some impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Load all of your sprites before your game starts, in a static class.  This way, you only have to load your sprites once, and you can use them for the entirety of your game instance.  Something like this:

```
public static class SpriteData 
{
    public static Sprite[] Sprites;

    public static void Load()
    {
        if (Sprites == null) {
            Sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("sprites");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your game logic, call the load function:

```
SpriteData.Load();
```

Then use your sprites where you need them:

```
Sprite sprite = SpriteData.Sprites[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try that and update you about the performance.

Comment: Hi! I implemented the solution but unfortunately it didn't work for me the game still takes time to load each level, anyway I am really thankful of you taking time to answer my question. Although there is one thing I want to know(I hope I am not going off-topic), the game is for website and I am building a webGL app so should I stick with my previous sprite loading technique or should I use yours? Since the preloading thing would take almost 800 sized array and loading on each level would take only 90 sized array each level.